# Swift: Displaying HTML data in a label using NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html slow

Tags: html, ios, swift4

I am using **NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html** to display html formated string on several labels on a tableview cell as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!

     let htmlDescription = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: self.Structures[indexPath.section].description.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                     .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

             cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
             cell.textLabel?.attributedText = htmlDescription

    return cell

}
```

This works as expected however its very slow and the view appears frozen until the operation is completed. This is terrible for production level work. My question is how can  I optimize this to prevent the freezing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue. While @LGP solution might be the one for you, I sufficed with a less tricky solution - and it might be enough for you too. What was really inefficient in my case was parsing the HTML to `NSAttributedString`. Which will have to happen even in @LGP's solution.

I used a very simple approach - when I was loading the data from the backend, as a part of parsing the response I have also parsed the HTML. That made the backend call more lengthy (of course), but then the model itself contained already `NSAttributedString` instead of a `String` that needed to be parsed.

If you try it, your `cellForRow` will look something like this (but I guess that's clear from what I tried to explain):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!

    let htmlDescription = self.Structures[indexPath.section].attributedDescription
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = htmlDescription
    return cell
}
```

Which will make rendering of the table less resources demanding and faster (in my case it was a difference between laggy scrolling, and smooth scrolling).

Of course in that case somewhere during model parsing you'll have to use:

```
self.attributedDescription = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: description.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                 .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
        documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: Your approach is interesting. Still using this approach what would be the effect of moving the mode parsing logic to a  DispatchQueue and showing a visual indicator of progress indicator? are there any issues with running this on a  DispatchQueue?

Comment: @JamesWahome it's always running on a DispatchQueue.. do you mean on a background thread? if so, it might be better, but I would still recommend doing it just once when you get the data, and not in the `cellForRowAt`, because that's obviously just wasting resources.. if you run it on background thread, then you will have to provide some syncing logic to make sure it works properly with the cell layout...

Comment: yes I meant on a background thread and yes only when the data is being fetched and not on the cellForRowAt

Comment: @JamesWahome ok, documentation for `NSAttributedString` explicitly states that you cannot do HTML parsing on any other thread than main thread (see discussion section in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init ), therefore as it states, you can expect a timeout and failure. Thus you will HAVE to keep it on main thread for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately HTML rendering is *very* slow when using native iOS API's. I have had exactly the same problem, trying to populate a table view with cell contents based on HTML data. I did a lot of tests and research, trying to find a faster solution, but didn't really find anything better.

Eventually I went with a solution with a queue that renders the HTML into an image, then update the table view cell with it when it is ready. There are several things to look out for if you choose this solution.

- Most of the work cannot be done in a background thread, because the `NSAttributedString` function that does the conversion explicitly requires it to operate on the main thread. The purpose is rather to serialize the work.
- The background queue need to limit the number of workers to not eat
  up too much memory and CPU. Try one or two to start with.
- You need to detect when rendering is complete, to take the snapshot, which at least in my case, was quite tricky. Perhaps not so much a problem if you use `UILabel`, but more so with `WkWebView` and `UIWebView`, as they have problems with this.
- You will want to put placeholder images into the cells while they are rendering, preferably of the same size as the resulting image. If you have dynamic cell heights you need to update the height when rendering is done. This will add to complexity.
- This solution will probably not render faster, but will at least greatly improve responsiveness, as it doesn't hog the main thread nearly as much as putting HTML into each cells.

While it is quite a complex and far from optimal solution, it did improve my app from an unusable state to fairly good. If anyone does have a better solution I am all ears.